# Masonry Images don't like the <div>

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-masonry, masonry

So i am trying to create a gallery of photographs using Masonry. They may all be different sizes so i went with using % sizing instead to sort of let things pan out a bit cleaner. Now i wanted to add on info on top of the photo and also make things filterable.

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<script src="~/Scripts/Isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Isotope/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Isotope/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Isotope/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.Gallery').masonry();
</script>
<style>
    img {
        max-width: 33%;
    }
</style>
</head>




<body>
<div>
    <p></p>
    <div class="Gallery">

        @foreach (var pic in Model)
        {
        <div class="photo-container">
            <a href='@Url.Action("Details", "PhotoManagement", new { id = 
                  pic.Id })'><img src="@pic.FilePath" typeof="image" 
                  oncontextmenu="return false" /></a>
        </div>
            <script>
                var $Gallery = $('.Gallery').isotope({
                    // options...
                });
                $Gallery.imagesLoaded().progress(function () { 
                $Gallery.isotope('layout');  });
            </script>
        }
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Photo of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2joeu.png)
Any tips you guys have I would appreciate it! Also any criticisms or anything you would suggest i do to improve would also be great. I'm practicing around with c# and just trying to learn more about it all but stuff like this is frustrating to understand where i went wrong.

Side Note: i have also tried using append to append all the images and it didn't work either :(

Answer (score 1):

HEAD

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<script src="~/Scripts/Isotope/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Isotope/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Isotope/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

 <style>
    .photo-container{
        width: 320px;
        margin: 5px;
        float: left;
    }
    .photo-container img {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

BODY
`

```
   <div>
       <p></p>
         <div class="Gallery">

             @foreach (var pic in Model)
        {
            <div class="photo-container">
                <a href='@Url.Action("Details", "PhotoManagement", new { id =
              pic.Id })'>
                    <img src="@pic.FilePath" typeof="image"
                         oncontextmenu="return false" />
                </a>
            </div>
        }
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var $grid = $('.Gallery').isotope({
                    itemSelector: ".photo-container",
                    masonry: {
                        columnWidth: 33
                    }
                });
                $grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function () {
                    $grid.isotope('layout');
                })
            })

        </script>
       </div>
   </div>`
```

A buddy went and helped me and we got it working with the following solution. If this helps anyone else down the line